# What are the Diablo 3 Hardcaps?

Tags: diablo-iii

**What are the Diablo 3 Hardcaps?**

I am having trouble finding official posts or people that have tested these values.

Please provide the source of your information as well.

Thanks

Comment: why do you think diablo 3 has hardcaps?

Comment: I keep seeing in some posts and articles online talking about hardcaps on some stats. They are mostly before the patch 2.0.1 and before ROS. Mainly speculating about Hardcaps. So, i am just wondering if hardcaps exist and if so, what are they?

Comment: I think there was some speculation that blizz was looking into hard capping some stats like crit chance/crit damage, etc but that never happened.

Comment: This may not be exactly what you mean, but paragon points do have some caps: the bonuses in the Offensive, Defensive, and Utility categories have caps, and after you reach a certain (insane) point, you have to put all paragon points into the Core Stats category.

Comment: @Wikwocket, that is not what i am talking about. =P

Comment: I know, but as the discussion is already trending towards there being no caps per se, I thought I would add what relevant information I could. ;)

Comment: There are definitely caps for block % and block dmg reduction.  Same with movement speed, gold/magic find. If I'm not mistaken crit chance and crit dmg both have caps too, but I'm not sure about those two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only hardcaps that I'm aware of are:

- 25% movement speed
- 300% magic find

Bonuses from items and from paragon levels for these stats are treated with the same cap. For example, if you have 20% movement speed from Paragon levels and 10% from your boots, you will still only have 25% bonus movespeed total. The monk passive Fleet Footed, however, bypasses this cap and can bring your movespeed to 35% bonus, since that's not from paragon points or items.

---

Edit: As of [patch 2.0.5](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/14138344/patch-205-now-live-5-13-2014#general). The hard cap for gold find was removed.

Comment: And the same can be said about shrines and pylons, right? (bypassing the cap)

Comment: @prolink007 Yes, they are also exempt from the cap. If you grab a Fleeting Shrine or Speed Pylon, you'll still get a temporary speed boost over the cap.

Comment: @prolink007 there are also many skills that lets you temporarily go over the 25%, the limit is only for permenant speed boost via gear or passives.  There is a crusader passive lowers it to 10% (while not in town)

Comment: This is a great answer to the question. However, is there any confirmation on these being the ONLY hard caps currently? Any blue posts or tests?

Comment: At one point in time there was a hard cap on damage reduction from armor / all res.  I believe that has been removed. The MS cap is only from gear, skills can take you above that (including passives such as fleet footed or tactical advantage). There are soft caps (gear cap) on Critical Chance, Critical Damage, Block Chance, etc.

Comment: It now goes up to 400% Gold Find for difficulties since update.

Comment: @WASasquatch Do you have a source for that? Torment difficulties can give well over 300% gold find, but that doesn't count towards the cap. I haven't heard anything of the item/paragon cap changing, however.